# Problem with Bibliography Style (ACM)

Tags: bibtex, punctuation, acm

I am a newbie in Latex and forgive me if the question seems dum.
I have the following entry in my Bibliography.

```
@misc{fuller2011,
 author               = {V. Fuller and D. Farinacci and D. Meyer and D. Lewis},
 month                = {June},
 organization         = {Internet Engineering Task Force},
 publisher            = {IETF},
 series               = {Request for Comments},
 title                = {LISP Alternative Topology (LISP+ALT)},
 year                 = {2011},
 howpublished         = {http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-lisp-alt-07},
 }
```

When I use `\bibliographystyle{plain}`, I see the following in the subsequent .pdf:

```
    V. Fuller, D. Farinacci, D. Meyer, and D. Lewis. Lisp alternative topol-
ogy (lisp+alt). http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-lisp-alt-07, June
2011.
```

Which is OK.

But, when I use `\bibliographystyle{acm}`, (I am forced to use "acm") I see the following in the subsequent .pdf:

```
Fuller, V., Farinacci, D., Meyer, D., and Lewis, D. Lisp
alternative topology (lisp+alt), http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-lisp-alt-07, June 2011.
```

You see that commas are put within one name (i.e. names are not displayed correctly). What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? I am using MikTEX 2.8 with TexNicCenter in Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to the `plain` bibliography style, the `acm` style uses a lastname/firstname scheme to display author names, and it is common for this scheme to put a comma between the different name parts. Have a look at the [ACM LaTeX style guide](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/) -- commas between last name and first name are the way it's meant to be.

Comment: while it's true that the `acm` style (and lots of others) use this over-comma'ed style, it gets to be very hard to read when there are more than two authors.  and perish the thought that one of them should be a junior or similar!  the latest edition of *chicago* specifies that only the first author should be listed last-name-first, with the others in normal order.  earlier editions had all names last-name-first, but separated the names by semicolons to eliminate the confusion.  someone should suggest to acm that there are more scrutable styles.

Comment: The link no longer works. Could you provide an update, please?